# Over-riding style won't effect from flip-clock cdn

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, cdn, flipclock

I'm trying to use flip-clock in my nuxt project. It's working but when i try tocustomize the style, it doesn't reflect the changes

the HTML

```
<template>
  <div class="clock">
    <div id="flip-start" v-if="flipStart">
      <flip-clock @timer-stop="stopTimer"></flip-clock>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

the style

```
.flip-clock-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.flip-clock-divider,
.flip-clock-label {
  color: #7e92b5 !important;
  font-size: 25px !important;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto !important;
}
```

I'm trying to change the flip-clock label in particular

Comment: Are you using `<style scoped>` maybe ?

Comment: @Renaud, Yes , I am

Answer (score 0):

`.flip-clock-label[data-v-f3eg9whatever]` does not exist ;)

Put global CSS class in `<style></style>` and only the ones that should be scoped to the component in `<style scoped></style>` (you can have both)

Comment: so I can declare two styles in one component?

Comment: yes, <style> for your lib overrides and <style scoped> for your own components' style